# Excel Chart Sample Size

Tags: excel

i have an excel file here someone else created which automatically changes the data size depending on the number entered into a cell. i cant for the life of me figure out how they have done it.. but i want to use something similar myself.

I will have a list from perhaps, A1 to A100, sometimes there are 50 entries, other times 20. So i want the chart to just show how many entries rather than flat lining the empty entries. (the empty data will automatically show 0).

This excel file i have, does that (see picture) but how can i do it also?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the column is a dynamic array, you can reference it with a [spill range reference](https://exceljet.net/dynamic-array-formulas-in-excel) simply by `A1#`

Otherwise you can reference it by the formula `A1:INDEX(A:A,MAX(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))*ROW(A:A)))`. Note that this formula includes blank cells between the first and last non-empty cells.

Broken down, that formula is a reference *from* `A1` *to* the last cell in the `A:A` column (`INDEX(A:A,MAX(...*ROW(A:A))`) that has a value in it: `NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))`